# GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/user/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

Tags: permissions, gvfs, metadata

lately i've been getting this [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a13yp.png) whenver I start gedit and the error message seems to fill my terminal buffer.

PS: a day before I used nautilius to get access to usr/loacl/MATLAB directory so that I could install additional plugins to my MATLAB. But later closed the root access to the directory.

Can anyone tell me what's wrong ?

Comment: After fixing refrain from using sudo nautilus or sudo gedit commands.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This should be owned by you, so do one of two things:

1. Change owner to your user:

   ```
   sudo chown user.user ~/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home
   ```
2. Delete it:

   ```
   sudo rm ~/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home
   ```

Source:

https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2369792