# Ubuntu 18.04 update broke desktop config file

Tags: gnome

Latest update (now Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS) has broken a custom desktop configuration file (.desktop). The .png custom icon linked to in the file no longer displays and I get the trust and launch dialog on every launch. I believe the trust issue is what is blocking the icon display. This behavior started on 20 March 2020, when I ran an update.

The desktop config file points to a small c++ program in my bin folder. Both the applet and the desktop configuration file are executable.

I tried setting the trust metadata with gio, but get the error:
gio: Error setting file metadata: No such file or directory

Answer (score 0):

Managed to fix this. The answer is [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/963137) Just change the owner and group of the ~/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home file to your user. Now it will trust after opening the first time and the icon appears.